# How to extract tabular summary data from an lm command in R

Tags: r, format, extract, lm

I have data structured the following way:

```
group_id, months_from_start, perc_total_downloads, experience_ratio
1             1                    1.2                4
1             2                    1.7                6
…
235           1                    6.7                3
235           2                   18                  8
…
```

There are about 300 groups, each of which have 70 or so consecutive data elements.

I've issued the following script to estimate a second order polynomial for each of the groups.

```
s.1<-lm(xts(s[s$group_id == 1,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 1,][,2]))$perc_total_downloads ~ poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 1,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 1,][,2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw=TRUE))
s.235<-lm(xts(s[s$group_id == 235,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 235,][,2]))$perc_total_downloads ~ poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 235,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 235,][,2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw=TRUE))
s.599<-lm(xts(s[s$group_id == 599,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 599,][,2]))$perc_total_downloads ~ poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 599,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 599,][,2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw=TRUE))
s.1111<-lm(xts(s[s$group_id == 1111,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 1111,][,2]))$perc_total_downloads ~ poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 1111,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 1111,][,2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw=TRUE))
s.1537<-lm(xts(s[s$group_id == 1537,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 1537,][,2]))$perc_total_downloads ~ poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 1537,][,-2], order.by=as.Date(s[s$group_id == 1537,][,2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw=TRUE))
```

For each one of these new variables I can issue a summary statement to reveal interesting information:

```
> summary(s.44375)

Call:
lm(formula = xts(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, -2], order.by = as.Date(s[s$group_id == 
44375, ][, 2]))$perc_total_downloads ~ poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 
44375, ][, -2], order.by = as.Date(s[s$group_id == 44375, 
][, 2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw = TRUE))


Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-0.0064004 -0.0017315 -0.0002022  0.0012087  0.0078436 


Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
                                                                                                                                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                                                                                                       1.993e-03  1.137e-03   1.753    0.084 .  
poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, -2], order.by = as.Date(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, 2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw = TRUE)1.0  7.769e-04  6.707e-05  11.583   <2e-16 ***
poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, -2], order.by = as.Date(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, 2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw = TRUE)2.0 -9.258e-06  8.404e-07 -11.017   <2e-16 ***
poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, -2], order.by = as.Date(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, 2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw = TRUE)0.1         NA         NA      NA       NA    
poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, -2], order.by = as.Date(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, 2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw = TRUE)1.1         NA         NA      NA       NA    
poly(xts(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, -2], order.by = as.Date(s[s$group_id == 44375, ][, 2]))$months_from_start, 2, raw = TRUE)0.2         NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 


Residual standard error: 0.002866 on 69 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.6619,Adjusted R-squared: 0.6521 
F-statistic: 67.53 on 2 and 69 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

For my purpose I need to transcribe this information into a table, which is incredibly tedious and time consuming cutting and pasting from this format:

```
group_id   intercept est  intercept stnd err    intercept t value   …
44375         1.993e-03         1/137e-03           1.753          ...
…
```

It would also be convenient for me to have conventional notation rather than scientific notation, but I imagine I could live without that.

Is there any way for me to do this without cutting and pasting by hand?

Thanks  --sw

Answer (score 3):

The summary function just returns an R list. For example,

```
R> x = runif(10);y=runif(10)
R> m = lm(y ~ x)
```

The part you are interested in is the fourth element:

```
R> summary(m)[[4]]
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.44041     0.1768  2.4911  0.03746
x           -0.05899     0.3143 -0.1877  0.85579
```

This is just a matrix.

---

The above answers your question, but you code makes me want to weep! In particular, Read up on `for` loops and the `plyr` package. For example, I suspect the final two lines pretty much does everything you want:

```
##Load the package and create some data
library(plyr)
dd = data.frame(group_id = sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), x = runif(10), y=runif(10)) 

##Split up dd by group_id and do some regression
dd1 = ddply(dd, .(group_id), summarise, summary(lm(y ~ x))[[4]])

##Label the column names
colnames(dd1)[2:5] = c("Estimate"   "Std. Error" "t value"    "Pr(>|t|)")
```

Comment: Initialize a matrix, and do a loop that includes c(summary(m)$coef[,'Estimate'],summary(m)$coef[,'Std. Error'])...and so on

Comment: for what it's worth `coef(summary(m))` will also extract this information, although as @DWin has commented previously the name of the accessor method is a little inconsistent ... it should probably be `coefTable()` ...

Comment: I can never remember the accessor methods. I find it's quicker going through the list elements one by one for simple structures. The useful elements are typically near the top.

Comment: BTW, summary(m)[[4]] is not a dataframe, but rather a matrix. Try to access it with "$" and you will be disappointed.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Is there a way I can list the rows of the matrix in one line?