# R Return p-values for categorical independent variables with glm

Tags: r, p-value

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613620/loop-for-glm-model-with-changing-number-of-variables) about looping a glm command for all possible combinations of independent variables. Another user provided a great answer that runs all possible models, however I can't figure out how to produce a data.frame of all possible p-values.

The code suggested in the previous question works for independent variables that are binary (pasted below). However, several of my variables are categorical. Is there any way to adjust the code so that I can produce a table of all p-values for every possible model (there are 2,046 possible models with 10 independent variables...)?

```
# p-values in a data.frame
p_values <- 
  cbind(formula_vec, as.data.frame ( do.call(rbind,
        lapply(glm_res, function(x) {
          coefs <- coef(x)
          rbind(c(coefs[,4] , rep(NA, length(ind_vars) - length(coefs[,4]) + 1)))
        })
  )))
```

An example of one independent variable is "Bedrock" where possible categories include: "till," "silt," and "glacial deposit." It's not feasible to assign a numerical value to these variables, which is part of the problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it's possible to convert categorical variable into dummy variables? In your example, there will be three dummies.

Comment: That's just it; I was trying not to convert the variables and keep them as is; if it's possible.

Comment: So, you are treating categorical variables as continuous?

Comment: The assumption in the above code is that coefficient table has 1+#variables rows. It is not true in case of categorical variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of additional categorical variable IndVar4 (factor a, b, c) the coefficient table can be more than just a row longer. Adding variable IndVar4:

```
              Estimate Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.7548180  1.4005800 -1.2529223 0.2102340
IndVar1     -0.2830926  1.2076534 -0.2344154 0.8146625
IndVar2      0.1894432  0.1401217  1.3519903 0.1763784
IndVar3      0.1568672  0.2528131  0.6204867 0.5349374
IndVar4b     0.4604571  1.0774018  0.4273773 0.6691045
IndVar4c     0.9084545  1.0943227  0.8301523 0.4064527
```

Max number of rows is less then all variables + all categories:

```
max_values <- length(ind_vars) +
  sum(sapply( dfPRAC, function(x) pmax(length(levels(x))-1,0)))
```

So the new corrected function is:

```
p_values <- 
  cbind(formula_vec, as.data.frame ( do.call(rbind,
        lapply(glm_res, function(x) {
          coefs <- coef(x)
          rbind(c(coefs[,4] , rep(NA, max_values - length(coefs[,4]) + 1)))
        })
  )))
```

But the result is not so clean as with continuous variables. I think Metrics' idea to convert every categorical variable to (levels-1) dummy variables gives same results and maybe cleaner presentation.

### Data:

```
dfPRAC <- structure(list(DepVar1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), DepVar2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                                      1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                         IndVar1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
                                     0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 

                         IndVar2 = c(1, 3, 9, 1, 5, 1, 
                                                                             1, 8, 4, 6, 3, 15, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 10, 1, 9, 9, 11, 5), 
                         IndVar3 = c(0.500100322564443, 1.64241601558441, 0.622735778490702, 
                                     2.42429812749226, 5.10055213237027, 1.38479786027561, 7.24663629203007, 
                                     0.5102348706939, 2.91566510995229, 3.73356170379198, 5.42003495939846, 
                                     1.29312896116503, 3.33753833987496, 0.91783513806083, 4.7735736131668, 
                                     1.17609362602233, 5.58010703426296, 5.6668754863739, 1.4377813063642, 
                                     5.07724130837643, 2.4791994535923, 2.55100067348583, 2.41043629522981, 
                                     2.14411703944206)), .Names = c("DepVar1", "DepVar2", "IndVar1", 
                                                                    "IndVar2", "IndVar3"), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame")

dfPRAC$IndVar4 <- factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"),8))
dfPRAC$IndVar5 <- factor(rep(c("d", "e", "f", "g"),6))
```

### Set up the models:

```
dep_vars <- c("DepVar1", "DepVar2") 
ind_vars <- c("IndVar1", "IndVar2", "IndVar3", "IndVar4", "IndVar5")

# create all combinations of ind_vars
ind_vars_comb <- 
  unlist( sapply( seq_len(length(ind_vars)), 
          function(i) {
               apply( combn(ind_vars,i), 2, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "+"))
          }))

# pair with dep_vars:
var_comb <- expand.grid(dep_vars, ind_vars_comb ) 

# formulas for all combinations
formula_vec <- sprintf("%s ~ %s", var_comb$Var1, var_comb$Var2)

# create models
glm_res <- lapply( formula_vec, function(f)   {
    fit1 <- glm( f, data = dfPRAC, family = binomial("logit"))
    fit1$coefficients <- coef( summary(fit1))
    return(fit1)
})
names(glm_res) <- formula_vec
```