# Combination of two lists with partial string matching (in R)

Tags: r, list, combinations

I am trying to find all the combinations of two lists, however the second list is essentially repetition of the first lists variables with added brackets etc., as shown below.

```
other_cols <- c("C", "D", "E", "F")

other_colsRnd <- c("(1|C)", "(1|D)", "(1|E)", "(1|F)")

# I have some code to do combinations from one list:

combos = do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(other_cols), function(y) {
  arrangements::combinations(other_cols, y, layout = "l")
}))

theBigList = sapply(combos, paste, collapse = " + ")

> theBigList
 [1] "C"             "D"             "E"             "F"             "C + D"         "C + E"         "C + F"         "D + E"         "D + F"        
[10] "E + F"         "C + D + E"     "C + D + F"     "C + E + F"     "D + E + F"     "C + D + E + F"
```

I would like the full list of combinations in `theBigList` of both of them combined, *without* any repetition of `C` and `(1|C)`

########

edit
`C` or `D` etc. are shorthand versions of the "real" variables, which look more like:

```
other_cols <- c("Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot")
other_colsRnd <- c("(1|Charlie)", "(1|Delta)", "(1|Echo)", "(1|Foxtrot)")
```

########

The expected outcome is something like this, though stored order will not be important.

```
theBigList
"C"  "(1|C)"  "D"  "(1|D)"  "E"  "(1|E)"  "F"  "(1|F)"  "C + D"
"C + (1|D)"  "C + E"  "C + (1|E)"  "C + F"  "C + (1|F)"
"D + E"  "D + (1|E)"  "D + F"  "D + (1|F)"      
"E + F"  "E + (1|F)"
"C + D + E"  "(1|C) + D + E"  "(1|C) + (1|D) + E"  "(1|C) + (1|D) + (1|E)" etc.
```

Is there a way to put the `lapply` inside the `lapply`?

Or, I am currently thinking I can `comboRnd` e.g

```
combosRnd = do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(other_cols), function(y) {
  arrangements::combinations(other_colsRnd, y, layout = "l")
}))
```

and then take inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613620/loop-for-glm-model-with-changing-number-of-variables?rq=1) using `var_comb <- expand.grid(combos, combosRnd)` with some sort of `if` and `grep` to detect the "same" variables, that I haven't worked out yet.

###### edit

I think I think, I can add combos e.g. something like

```
theBigList = sapply(combos, paste, collapse = " + ")
theBigListRnd = sapply(combosRnd, paste, collapse = " + ")
comboBigList = c(theBigList, theBigListRnd)
var_comb <- expand.grid(combos, combosRnd)
var_comb2 <- expand.grid(theBigList, theBigListRnd)
```

... so `comboBigList` has all the ones where there is no crossover whatsoever, and then I can remove any "lines" in either or `var_comb` or `var_comb2` that have that have matching anything matching in the `var` columns.

*Yes*, this is a smaller easier chunk of my previously asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630456/how-to-change-combinations-of-random-and-fixed-effects-automatically-for-lmer-fo), however I have refined it to the bare necessity for me to get this infernal analysis done, as it seems that I may have been biting off more than I can chew on that one. I will brute force the nestings I need with this as a supplement (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not combine `other_cols` and `other_colsRnd` and use the same code that you have.

```
combine_vec <- c(other_cols, other_colsRnd)

combos <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(combine_vec), function(y) {
  arrangements::combinations(combine_vec, y, layout = "l")
}))

theBigList = sapply(combos, paste, collapse = " + ")
theBigList

#  [1] "C"                                            
#  [2] "D"                                            
#  [3] "E"                                            
#  [4] "F"                                            
#  [5] "(1|C)"                                        
#  [6] "(1|D)"                                        
#  [7] "(1|E)"                                        
#  [8] "(1|F)"                                        
#  [9] "C + D"                                        
# [10] "C + E"                                        
# [11] "C + F"                                        
# [12] "C + (1|C)" 
#...
#...
```

From this `theBigList` you can drop the `variable + (1|variable)` combination using the following code.

```
library(stringr)

finalList <- theBigList[!mapply(function(x, y) any(x %in% y) || any(y %in% x), 
    str_extract_all(theBigList, '\\b[A-Z](?!\\))'), 
    str_extract_all(theBigList, '(?<=1\\|)[A-Z]'))]
```

Comment: That works for the initial combination but I can't have a line like "C + (1|C)" in the final list. If there is a list like your `theBigList` (or in the `expand.grid` idea I had before `var_comb`), the some pseudocode might say: loop through and check for multiples of the variable "C". i.e. `If C & (1|C) are in the same line delete it.` Though it would loop through `other_cols` to check for all the ones to delete.

Comment: So you don't want any combinations of `variable + (1|variable)` in the output? So also drop values like `"(1|C) + (1|D) + D"` ?

Comment: yes, that is correct. My latest attempt doesn't work yet and also seems inelegant: `newBigList <- NULL
for (l in combos3){
  for (m in other_cols){
    if (str_detect(m, paste("(1|", m, ")", sep = "")) == FALSE){
      newBigList <- c(combos3[l], newBigList)
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @MrSwaggins See my updated answer. That might help.

Comment: Almost. Hugely sorry, I should have said that I am only using `C`, `D` etc. as shorthand place holders for the variables. The real variables are more like `other_cols <- c("Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot")
other_colsRnd <- c("(1|Charlie)", "(1|Delta)", "(1|Echo)", "(1|Foxtrot)")`

Comment: You may change the regex based on your actual data. So instead of `[A-Z]` you may use `\\w+` to extract one word instead of one letter.